# Evergreen test: $ is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to transfer code used by Evergreen/jasmine combo. Going from an old version of the project to the new version. After transferring all the need files the test is not working and says:

$ is not defined

From the debugger, it looks as though my required() js files cannot be found:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:38545/public/javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

The following files are what I have transferred:

config/evergreen.rb

```
require 'capybara-webkit'
Evergreen.configure do |config|
  config.driver = :webkit
  config.public_dir = "/"
  config.spec_dir = "spec/javascripts"
  config.template_dir = "spec/javascripts/templates"
end
```

spec/javascripts/
spec/javascripts/helpers/*
spec/javascripts/support/*
spec/javascripts/templates/*

Manually checking the file by navigating, I see that in the old project, the file is available, but on the new project, I get a sinatra page saying

"Sinatra doesnt know this ditty"

The jquery file is in the same place, and I can't see any obvious changes to the routes file. What steps should I take in debugging this?

**UPDATE**

It seems changing the sinatra gem from 1.2.6 to 1.2.7 fixes this (a difference in the two projects). Still working out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems changing the sinatra gem from 1.2.6 to 1.2.7 fixes this (a difference in the two projects).